# Fill in numpy array using fancy indexing

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have an say NxM called Image, and I have 3 1xK arrays, x_array, y_array, z_array where x_array and y_array represent index values and z_array represents value to insert, ex:

```
Image[y_array[0], x_array[0]] = z_array[0]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly index using the arrays:

```
Image[x_array, y_array] = z_array
```